# Using Email tokenizer in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

Did try some examples from elasticsearch documentation and from google but nothing helped in figuring out..

just a sample data I have is just few blog posts. I am trying to see all posts with email address. When I use `"email":"someone"` I see all the posts matching `someone` but when I change to use `someone@gmail.com` nothing shows up!

```
    "hits": [
             {
                "_index": "blog",
                "_type": "post",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                   "user": "sreenath",
                   "email": "someone@gmail.com",
                   "postDate": "2011-12-12",
                   "body": "Trying to figure out this",
                   "title": "Elastic search testing"
                }
             }
           ]
```

when I use Get query is as shown below, I see all posts matching `someone@anything.com`. But I want to change this 
`{ "term" : { "email" : "someone" }}` to `{ "term" : { "email" : "someone@gmail.com" }}`

```
GET blog/post/_search
{ 
 "query" : { 
   "filtered" : { 
     "filter" : { 
       "and" : [ 
         { "term" :
            { "email" : "someone" }
         }
       ] 
     } 
   } 
 } 
}
```

I did the curl -XPUT for the following, but did not help

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/  -d '
{
   "settings" : {
      "analysis" : {
         "filter" : {
            "email" : {
               "type" : "pattern_capture",
               "preserve_original" : 1,
               "patterns" : [
                  "([^@]+)",
                  "(\\p{L}+)",
                  "(\\d+)",
                  "@(.+)"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer" : {
            "email" : {
               "tokenizer" : "uax_url_email",
               "filter" : [ "email", "lowercase",  "unique" ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a custom analyzer for email addresses but you are not using it. You need to declare the `email` field in your mapping type to actually use that analyzer, like below. Also make sure to create the right index with that analyzer, i.e. `blog` and not `test`

```
                       change this
                            |
                            v
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/blog/  -d '{
   "settings" : {
      "analysis" : {
         "filter" : {
            "email" : {
               "type" : "pattern_capture",
               "preserve_original" : 1,
               "patterns" : [
                  "([^@]+)",
                  "(\\p{L}+)",
                  "(\\d+)",
                  "@(.+)"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer" : {
            "email" : {
               "tokenizer" : "uax_url_email",
               "filter" : [ "email", "lowercase",  "unique" ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {              <--- add this
      "post": {
         "properties": {
            "email": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "email"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```